# How to implement a typed tagless interpreter?

Tags: isabelle

[1] describes a very interesting approach to define a language syntax and semantics. The idea is to use classes instead of ADTs to describe a syntax:

```
class ExpSYM =
  fixes lit :: "int ⇒ 'a"
    and neg :: "'a ⇒ 'a"
    and add :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"
```

Semantics is described using a class instantiation for a some value domain (`int`):

```
instantiation int :: ExpSYM
begin
definition "lit_int (n :: int) ≡ n"
definition "neg_int (e :: int) ≡ -e"
definition "add_int (e1 :: int) (e2) ≡ e1 + e2"
instance ..
end

definition eval :: "int ⇒ int" where
  "eval ≡ id"
```

Here is some examples:

```
term "add (lit 1) (lit 2)"
term "eval (add (lit 1) (lit 2))"
value "eval (add (lit 1) (lit 2))"
```

The approach allows to extend a language easily:

```
class MulSYM =
  fixes mul :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a"

instantiation int :: MulSYM
begin
definition "mul_int (e1 :: int) (e2) ≡ e1 * e2"
instance ..
end

term "eval (mul (add (lit 1) (lit 2)) (lit 5))"
value "eval (mul (add (lit 1) (lit 2)) (lit 5))"
```

Also the approach allows to define language semantics without value tags and pattern matching:

```
datatype val = BoolVal bool | IntVal int | StringVal string
```

The problem is that I can't implement the following Haskell example from [2] in Isabelle HOL:

```
class Symantics repr where
    int :: Int → repr Int
    add :: repr Int → repr Int → repr Int
    lam :: (repr a → repr b) → repr (a → b)
    app :: repr (a → b) → repr a → repr b
```

Author calls it s**y**mantics, because

> the class declaration defines the syntax of the embedded language (its
>   expression forms); class instances define interpretations, or the
>   semantics.

`repr` is a parameter representing a type instance of the class. This type is parametric. It can take `Int` as parameter (`repr Int`), or it can take an arrow type (`repr (a → b)`).

Here is an example of language expressions with different types:

```
th1 = add (int 1) (int 2)
−− th1 :: (Symantics repr) ⇒ repr Int
th2 = lam (\x → add x x)
−− th2 :: (Symantics repr) ⇒ repr (Int → Int)
th3 = lam (\x → add (app x (int 1)) (int 2))
−− th3 :: (Symantics repr) ⇒ repr ((Int → Int) → Int)
```

Here is the interpreter of the language:

```
newtype R a = R{unR :: a}

instance Symantics R where
    int x = R x
    add e1 e2 = R $ unR e1 + unR e2
    lam f = R $ unR ◦ f ◦ R
    app e1 e2 = R $ (unR e1) (unR e2)

−− eval :: R a → a
eval e = unR e
```

How to implement an analogous interpreter in Isabelle HOL? It seems that classes and locales aren't applicable here.

There is also a similar tagless interpreter based on generalized algebraic data types in the lecture notes [3]:

```
data Exp env t where
    B :: Bool → Exp env Bool
    V :: Var env t → Exp env t
    L :: Exp (a,env) b → Exp env (a → b)
    A :: Exp env (a → b) → Exp env a → Exp env b

data Var env t where
    VZ :: Var (t, env) t
    VS :: Var env t → Var (a, env) t

eval :: env → Exp env t → t
eval env (V v) = lookp v env
eval env (B b) = b
eval env (L e) = \x → eval (x, env) e
eval env (A e1 e2) = (eval env e1) (eval env e2)
```

Could you suggest how to implement these two tagless interpreters in Isabelle HOL?

---

[1] Oleg Kiselyov. Typed Tagless Final Interpreters

[2] --//--. Section 3.4 Tagless final embedding with higher-order abstract syntax. Page 29

[3] --//--, Section 3.2 Tagless, initial and final embeddings. Pages 22-23